# Migration from OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect: cannot use the openid_id to select appengine users

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-openid, openid-connect

Using Appengine/Java

I am migration OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect (OAuth 2.0 for Login), als explained here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID?hl=ja

I'm into step 3: Map (the existing) OpenID 2.0 identifiers to (new) OpenID Connect identifiers.

It says to 'In your user database, link the openid_id to the new sub ID.' The problem is that I cannot select my existing users with the openid_id, as in my existing user table Is used the com.google.appengine.api.users.User.getUserId() as a value to identify the user.

(I also did persist the complete com.google.appengine.api.users.User object)

Any idea how I can use the openid_id to select appengine users?

Comment: Follow up question: does the userid returned by getUserId() match the sub field of the idtoken returned in the migration flow? (see http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken). Presumably no, otherwise you could perform the mapping in step 3 based on userids instead of openid_id, right?

Comment: Indeed no, the sub is different from getUserId(). I ve tested this

Answer (score 0):

com.google.appengine.api.users.User.getFederatedIdentity() returns the openid_id (https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx). As I can't select on that to identify the user, I will use the coming months to populate that in my DB, so I can use that to select the proper user.